# Recreate Fragment of - View Pager - FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my application I am using ViewPager from the support library- v4

1. In main screen I have viewPager which got max 5 Fragment, all fragment belongs to one class ArticlePager
2. Now in main screen there are list on categories, now the content of the pager is based on that selection,

The problem I am having is, I have used `FragmentPagerAdapter`which stores the Fragment and if the fragment is already exist, It will return the old Fragment without recreating it. That things runs perfectly, but Problem Occurs @ the time of orientation change.

For instance

If there are 5 View normally in every fragment For the given position, but There are also some which contains 2-3 views. **Now** if I **change the orientation** on page No. lets say 5 which contains *only 3 view inside*.

So, by now in every category on Page 5 I'll got the view containing 3 view, which is not something I want.

In my application each category contains the pagination

**Is there any way such that i can destroy and recreate the Fragment on click of category?** or any other work around

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK thanks to open source I find my solution, [`FragmentPagerAdapter`](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/compatibility/AndroidSupportV2/src/android/support/v2/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java?r=3488) I have override the method `instantiateItem` and got the solution.

This can be easily achieved by [`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/compatibility/AndroidSupportV2/src/android/support/v2/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java?r=3488) such that it doesn't store the fragment. It recreate it all the time, but I don't want that in 100's of page because of only few pages.

Comment: How do you override it?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, your problem is that after rotation, the wrong set of fragments are in you ViewPager?

Why don't you check the current selected tab in onResume() or onStart() of your Activity, and create/assign a new PagerAdapter for you ViewPager with the correct fragments?

Comment: actually FragmentPagerAdapter stores the newly created fragment by tag in FragmentManager now if the fragment for the position is already created then it simply pass the object of last fragment without creating it. no matter how many object I'll create for the adapter.

Comment: now when i switch the orientation and if there are only 3 view for the position one then it will keep that same for all the tab